# Не работает сайт

Tags: vps

Есть сайт на вордпресс. Попросили перенести сайт на VPS (был выбран бегет)

Хар-ки сервера: Debian 9, Vesta CP (панель управления сервером).

Что было сделано: создан сервер, установлены БД и файлы сайта.

В чем проблема: прописал у себя на компе в хосте IP и домен сайта (чтоб проверить работает ли сайт). Если смотреть сайт через http - то все нормально, сайт работает (правда приходится в `.htacces` прописывать насильно переход на `http`). Если же смотреть через https - то выдает ошибку(ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

До этого, буквально за пару дней до переноса, был установлен SSL-сертификат и соответственно сайт переехал на https (на старом хостинге).

На новом же сервере SSL-сертификат не хочет устанавливаться (Error: Let's Encrypt validation status 400)

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема...

PS. Так же есть еще такой вопрос: как мне сделать доступными файлы сайта по IDE/FTP если по инструкции бегета я поменял хозяина папки `public_html` на `www-data`. И хотя я захожу от админа в этой папке получаю отказ доступа (Хотя через файловый менеджер бегета вполне себе захожу туда)

PPS Ни разу ни бекендер... Обычный фронт с минимумом знаний.

Comment: Ну проблема явно в невозможности получить сертификат. На время можно шифранутся Lets Encrypt. А по сути напишите в тех.поддержку хостеру. PS если вы поменяли хозяина на www-data, то root и другие пользователи уже не владелцы этой папки и видеть её не могут.

Comment: @Dmitriy, `root ... видеть её не могут`. Не правда, root может все, на уровне ядра для него отключены такие проверки. ТС, чтобы понять, что не так с правами, выберите проблемный каталог/файл, затем зайдите по ssh и введите следующее `ls -ld путь/проблемный-каталог-или-файл`, например `ls -ld /home/user/public_html`. Апач скорее всего запущен под `www-data`, для дебиана это стандартно. Затем напишите группы, в которых пользователь, под которым у вас не получается что-то сделать. Зайдите под ним по ssh, затем `whoami`, затем `groups`. Все что вывелось - сюда.

Comment: @TotalPusher да да я не прав, За root`a отвечу. Я редиска